# CSS Vertical line for tree menu

Tags: html, css

I am making tree view for sub menu items and I am almost done. The problem with the last element, how it looks now:
[image]

I want to look it like:
[image]

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bijoxoyeno/edit?html,css,output)

HTML:

```
  <ul class="menu-items">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Example 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Tree</a>
      <ul class="sub-items">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Example 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Example 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And styles:

```
.menu-items
  li
    padding 9px 0
    list-style-type none
    &.active
      a
        color $text-color
        font-weight 700

  .sub-items
    padding-left 15px
    padding-top 5px

    li
      position relative
      border-left 1px solid #000

    li::before
      position relative
      top -4px
      width 15px
      border-bottom 1px solid #000
      content ''
      display inline-block
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a tree in HTML using pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922247/how-to-get-a-tree-in-html-using-pure-css)

Comment: @SamuilPetrov I want to understand how to solve the problem for MY code, if it's possible. I know that there are dozens ways to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to add to your CSS

```
li:last-child {
 height: 1px;
}
```

check demo http://jsbin.com/tigepavemi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Indeed. It' works. Thank you!!! Will accept answer in 10 minutes, SO don't give me do it now,

Comment: Clean solution +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use an additional `pseudoelement` on the last `li`

```css
.menu-items li {
  padding: 9px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-items li.active a {
  color: red;
  font-weight 700
}

.sub-items {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.sub-items li {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.sub-items li::before {
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  width: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub-items li:last-of-type {
  border-left: none;
}

.sub-items li:last-of-type:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 18px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-items">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Example 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tree</a>
    <ul class="sub-items">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Example 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Example 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code in your css

```
.menu-items .sub-items li {
    position: relative;
    border-left: 0px;
}

.menu-items .sub-items li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
}
.menu-items .sub-items li:last-child:after {
    height: 50%;
}
```